# Ubuntu swap ctrl with alt wirless keyboard - big problem after reboot

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, swap

i have problem with my keys swap.

I'm using "gnome-tweak-tool" tool and everything is good.
Keys are working properly. Problem is when my keyboard is going offline or after laptop reboot.
I have checked in tool to swap keys but keys are returning to standard functions.
Can i do something with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xbindkeys instead, this not only allows binding keyboard keys but you can also bound mouse buttons.

sudo apt-get install xbindkeys

**bind keys to other keys..**

If you want a key on your keyboard to call a different key on your keyboard, you will need an extra piece of software as xbindkeys does not support this on it's own. I know of two programs which we can use, xdotool and xte. I prefer xte so I'm going to use that.

Install it:

sudo apt-get install xautomation

The syntax for xte is like this:

xte 'command key/mousebutton/xyCoordinates'

Examples:

```
To call a single key press: xte 'key keyName'

To call a key combination: xte 'keydown keyName' 'keydown secondKeyName' 'keyup keyName' 'keyup secondKeyName

To call a mouse button: xte 'mouseclick buttonNumber' (We'll discuss finding button numbers a little latter)

To move the mouse: xte 'mousemove xCoordinate yCoordinate'

And more! Read man xte
```

Now that you know the command for simulating key presses you can call it from your xbindkeys script, like this:

"xte 'key b'"
Control+b

As you might guess, this calls xte 'key b' when we press Ctrl+b, which would enter a b into any document you might be currently working on.

I thing to note however is that xbindkeys and xte don't always work very well together. Sometimes you have to press the keys exactly at the same time to get output, other times it works just fine.

**Other options are Xev and xmodmap**

These two comes pre installed in ubuntu.

Xev "creates a window and then asks the X server to send it events whenever anything happens to the window (such as it being moved, resized, typed in, clicked in, etc.)."

xmodmap is a "program is used to edit and display the keyboard modifier map and keymap table that are used by client applications to convert event keycodes into keysyms."